# Inline text formatting options with output to grid graphics object in R

Tags: r, graphics, text-formatting

I am using ggplot/R for report generation and want more fine-grained control over text formatting.

It's trivial to write some text, apply global formatting parameters, and output to a grid-graphics compatible object - just use [textGrob](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/grid.text.html).

```
t <- textGrob(
  label = "SOME TEXT"
 ,gp=gpar(fontsize=20, col="grey")
)

print(arrangeGrob(t))
```

Problem is that those formatting options only apply to the **entire** text string.  What I'm looking for is something that would offer basic inline formatting options (font size, bold, italic, etc) - ideally something lightweight like Markdown/CSS/HTML.  If I have to learn LaTeX, so be it, but that seems like overkill for what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not using markdown then to produce the reports (with [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) or [pander](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/)) and then transform that to pdf/docx/odt format with [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/)?

Comment: you should not be using `arrangeGrob` but `grid.draw` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a "text cursor" alongside `grid`'s functions for interrogating `grobs`. Say you had the phrase: "I want **this text bold**!!!!!!!, and you want the exclamation points in red:

```
grid.text("I want ", 
          name="notboldtext",
          hjust=0)  

text.cursor<-convertWidth(grobWidth("notboldtext") # Adds textGrob width & to location
              + unit(.5, "npc"), "npc")           

grid.text("this text bold",
          x=text.cursor, 
          gp=gpar(fontface="bold"),
          name="boldedtext",
          hjust=0)


text.cursor<- text.cursor + convertWidth(grobWidth("boldedtext"), "npc")

grid.text("!!!!!!!", 
          gp=gpar(col="red"),
          x=text.cursor,
          name="maptextnat", 
          hjust=0)
```

Comment: I'd add an image of the above, but I don't a suffient reputation points :-<